# Reset missing/deleted icons

Tags: software-installation

Just deleted the wifi(network) from the menu bar and now I do not have that icon on the task bar showing wifi  - How do I recover this?

Comment: You should provide mode tails (eg. your release of Ubuntu) to ensure any provided information works for you (instead of us guessing if you have Unity (14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS) or GNOME (18.04 LTS & 18.10) etc.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? How did you "delete" the wi-fi from the menu "bar"? Is wi-fi enabled in the wi-fi settings panel?

Comment: I am using an older Toshiba, with the 16.04LTS installed.  I have 250Gb HD, 2Gb ram.  I was attempting to attach the system to the School network via wifi.  THey have a logon prior to the attach to internet and you must first answer that before it will attach the internet.  When I installed the system it said it immediately linked to the internet without the logon screen.  As a result when Invoked the browser, I got the message that the internet was not available.  I then attempted to crawl inside the  icon on the upper task bar (right) with left or right click.  Nothing.

Comment: I then went to the left side and performed the similar clicks.  There I go to the setting for network.  Within there I again wanted to just jump into the logon screen and let their network take me the remainder of the way to that internet for yahoo.com.  When working within this area I accidentally pressed the delete key thinking it would cancel my exploration.  At that point I then lost the icon from settings and also the wifi detection from the taskbar.

Comment: Back to my question - I just wanted to get the settings shortcut back in my settings first.  Once I had that I believe that I could reset-up the wifi for my system and the taskbar icon would then also show backup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the indicator applet.

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete`

Comment: Attempted this and got error codes that from indicator on was not valid command on this computer system.